# how to give two different class reference to single UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

I want to implement two functionalities as color filling and view magnifying in my app. But the problem is that i can't be able to implement these two functionalities at same time. Because i have to specify two difference class reference for two functionalities  to my UIView, which can't be possible.

In other words, I have one view and i have given class reference as UIView (for color function). But for magnify function , i have to give class reference as MagnifyingView to that view. So, it is not possible to implement these two functionalities at same time.

So how can i give UIView and ACMagnifyingView two different class reference to single UIView at different conditions?

How can i do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: using delegate should resolve your problem ,,,

Comment: @Rohan - thanks for reply. Can you please explain how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `Categories`? check this tutorial http://iphone-obsessed.blogspot.com.br/2010/05/tutorial-creating-class-categories-in.html

can you provide more information? maybe if you provide more info i could help you more

**EDIT**

How `Categories` work:

you have a `UIView` class and you want some methods to use that you repeat a lot. what do you do: you create a category of `UIView` and add this method to your category, like this:

file `UIView+CustomView.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (CustomView)

- (void)myCustomMethod;

@end
```

file `UIView+CustomView.m`

```
#import "UIView+CustomView.h"

@implementation UIView (CustomView)

- (void)myCustomMethod {
  // Whatever you want to do with this UIView
}

@end
```

now, every time you need to use the `myCustomMethod` you just have to import `UIView+CustomView.h` and all `UIView` objects inside that class will have access to this method.

like this:

file `MainViewController.m`, header:

```
#import "UIView+CustomView.h"
```

file `MainViewController.m`, body, inside any method:

```
[myView myCustomMethod];
```

with this in mind i believe you could add your `ACMagnifyingView` as a subclass and this category to use your custom view

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually there is one UIView of class type UIView. But i want to implement magnifying functionality to my my app. So i have to give class type as ACMagnifyingView to that UIView on button click. how can i do this?

Comment: check my edit, if you want more details please share more details of your code